# Next.js conditional layout

Tags: next.js

I have changed _app.js to load layout depending upon which page is loaded. All work fine in development mode but once I create build it fails to get "Component.name" and returns empty value. Any suggestions please?

> my _app.js

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  switch (Component.name) {
    case "Home":
      return <Component {...pageProps} />;
    default:
      return (
        <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />{" "}
        </Layout>
      );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`name` is empty because code minification removes this values or obfuscates them, so you should not depend on the names of classes or functions.

For per page layout please follow [this official guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts)

Basically you create `getLayout` function for each page, and this function should return the layout:

```js
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import NestedLayout from '../components/nested-layout'

export default function Page() {
  return {
    /** Your content */
  }
}

Page.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <NestedLayout>{page}</NestedLayout>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

in `_app` use it like that:

```js
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout || ((page) => page)

  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}
```

Comment: This worked...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can use useRouter for this case.
As if when we create 404 page, nextJs navigates unknown paths to 404.js
we can take advantage of this feature.

//Layout.js

```
import Header from "./header.js"
import Footer from "./footer.js"
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar.js"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const router = useRouter()
  console.log("router", router)

  if (router.route === "/404") {
    return (
      <>
        <main>{children}</main>
      </>
    )
  }

 if(router.router === "/dashboard") {
 return (
 <Sidebar>{children}</Sidebar>
 )
 }
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

//_app.js

```
  <Component {...pageProps} />
```